# nginx rewrite with mapping

Tags: nginx, redirect

I ran into following rewrite & mapping problem and I'm not exactly sure what to do (but I think nginx map and nginx rewrite modules are the way to go)
I'd love to hear a few ideas. Thank you in advance - sorry for my bad english, I try to do my best. I need help with mapping with string2

URL structure: `domain.com/string1/string2/string3`

- if string1 = "this" then rewrite
- string2 should be mapped like

  hello -> abc
  whatsup -> xyz
  dontknow -> 1o1
- string3

so

`/example/hello/you` -> no redirection
`domain.com/this/whatsup/man` -> `domain.org/xyz/man`

hope you understand what I'm trying to say. Looking forward to hear from you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `string1` and `string2` do not contain a `/`, use a `rewrite` to capture `string3`, for example:

```
map $request_uri $new {
    default                 0;
    ~^/this/hello/          abc;
    ~^/this/whatsup/        xyz;
    ~^/this/dontknow/       1o1;
}

server {
    ...

    if ($new) {
        rewrite ^/[^/]+/[^/]+(.*)$ /$new$1 permanent;
    }

    ...
}
```